# EndpointNotFoundException 'Could not connect' because 'the target machine actively refused it' Connecting through Fiddler

Tags: .net, wcf, proxy, fiddler

I am encountering an issue trying to route my WCF client requests through Fiddler. I have searched the web high and low, and found only two references to Fiddler having problems when WCF services are configured to listen on IPv4, but IPv6 is enabled. However, while my issue is similar, it does not seem to be my problem.

I am encountering issues connecting to services hosted on IPv4 ports. The following exception is thrown by my WCF clients when my bindings are configured to use the fiddler proxy. I have disabled IPv6 support in Fiddler's options, and made sure my bindings are properly configured to use the proxy.

**Exception report:**

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException:
>   Could not connect to
>   http://campus.services.ecollege-labs.com/Entity/Foundation/v1.0/EducationalPartnerSvc.
>   TCP error code 10061: No connection
>   could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it
>   10.181.3.23:8888.  ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to
>   connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No
>   connection could be made because the
>   target machine actively refused it
>   10.181.3.23:8888    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint
>   endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress
>   socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean
>   connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6,
>   Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception&
>   exception)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext&
>   context)    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
>   Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   IMS.EnterpriseServices.Facades.Campus.EducationalPartner.EducationalPartnerSvc.FindByClientString(String
>   clientString)    at
>   IMS.EnterpriseServices.Facades.Campus.EducationalPartner.EducationalPartnerSvcClient.FindByClientString(String
>   clientString) in
>   C:\P4\HEDI\AS2-dev-dotnext-campus-dev\AS\HEI\Src\CAS\IMS.EnterpriseServices.Facades.Campus\Service
>   References\EducationalPartner\Reference.cs:line
>   428    at
>   IMS.EnterpriseServices.Facades.Campus.CampusEntityFacade.GetEPID(String
>   clientString) in
>   C:\P4\HEDI\AS2-dev-dotnext-campus-dev\AS\HEI\Src\CAS\IMS.EnterpriseServices.Facades.Campus\CampusEntityFacade.cs:line
>   37    at
>   IMS.EnterpriseServices.Transformation.Domain.TransformationSvc.TransformCreateGroupRequest(createGroupRequestMessage
>   message) in
>   C:\P4\HEDI\AS2-dev-dotnext-campus-dev\AS\HEI\Src\CAS\IMS.EnterpriseServices.Transformation.Domain\TransformationSvc.cs:line
>   106    at
>   IMS.EnterpriseServices.Facades.IMSFacade.TransformCreateGroupRequest(createGroupRequestMessage
>   imsMessage) in
>   C:\P4\HEDI\AS2-dev-dotnext-campus-dev\AS\HEI\Src\CAS\IMS.EnterpriseServices.Facades\IMSFacade.cs:line
>   113    at
>   IMS.EnterpriseServices.Domain.TransformationAndEnrichmentCoordinator.ProcessCreateGroupRequestMessage(createGroupRequestMessage
>   message) in
>   C:\P4\HEDI\AS2-dev-dotnext-campus-dev\AS\HEI\Src\CAS\IMS.EnterpriseServices.Domain\TransformationAndEnrichmentCoordinator.cs:line
>   140    at
>   IMS.EnterpriseServices.Facades.IMSFacade.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Object
>   o) in
>   C:\P4\HEDI\AS2-dev-dotnext-campus-dev\AS\HEI\Src\CAS\IMS.EnterpriseServices.Facades\IMSFacade.cs:line
>   135

**Binding Configuration:**

```
<customBinding>
  <!-- Secured, WS-Security message signing and encryption, custom binding for IMS endpoints -->
  <binding name="customHttpSecuredNoWSA">
    <security
      defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic128Rsa15"
      authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"
      securityHeaderLayout="Lax"
      includeTimestamp="false"
      keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy"
      messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
      messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
      requireSignatureConfirmation="false"
      requireSecurityContextCancellation="false"
      allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true">
      <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" />
    </security>
    <textMessageEncoding
      messageVersion="Soap11"
      writeEncoding="utf-8">
      <readerQuotas
        maxArrayLength="1048576"
        maxStringContentLength="4194304"
        maxBytesPerRead="4194304"
        maxNameTableCharCount="4194304"
      />
    </textMessageEncoding>
    <httpTransport
      maxBufferPoolSize="4194304"
      maxBufferSize="1048576"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576"
      proxyAddress="http://my.host.name:8888"
      useDefaultWebProxy="false"
    />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but does it happen when you *don't* go through Fiddler?

Comment: Can you `telnet 10.181.3.23 8888` with any success?  Can you connect it you configure it to go directly to the service?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Communication works fine when I do not go through Fiddler. It should also be noted that SoapUI, which is sending an initial request and hosting several mock services, communicates fine through fiddler.

Comment: @Paolo: As it turns out, trying to telnet **fails**. I'm a little surprised by this, as I mentioned to Skeet, SoapUI functions correctly with the fiddler proxy (it is configured to use 127.0.0.1:8888 as its proxy server). Any ideas why telnet would be failing as well?

Comment: @jrista - I suspect a DNS error or firewall issue then since 127.0.0.1 is a) the loopback address and b) unlikely to be firewalled.  10.181.3.23 may have windows firewall blocking you since it's presumably the primary LAN connection OR it may be the wrong IP for my.host.name (which is what you put in your config file)

Comment: @jrista: I wouldn't expect telnet to work through a *web* proxy. Have you tried using WireShark to work out what's going on at the network level?

Comment: @Jon - Note, I wasn't expecting it work as such, but it should at least connect to the proxy.  If you get a connection refused or similar error you know it's network-level rather than the proxy itself.

Comment: @Jon/Paolo: Thanks for the comments. I was able to resolve the issue with a little more research and a funky trick. See answer below.

Comment: @Skeet: `I wouldn't expect telnet to work through a *web* proxy.` Agreed, however, it appears Fiddler is an HTTP/HTTPS proxy (which I think is more broad than 'web'.) It is possible to `telnet 127.0.0.1 8888`, which successfully connects to the fiddler proxy. You can manually formulate requests, although fiddler seems to choke on all of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to comments from Jon Skeet and Paolo, I was able to resolve this issue. It appears that something (possibly a firewall) is interfering with connections to my host name/ip. Using 127.0.0.1 works, however it must be specified as follows in WCF configuration:

`proxyAddress="http://127.0.0.1.:8888"`

Note the extra period at the end of the 127.0.0.1 loopback address. Without the period, WCF has some kind of hard-coded check to prevent the use of a proxy server at your local loopback. (Why Microsoft would explicitly build in a hard-coded exclusion of the local loopback from proxy server usage is beyond me, but at least this trick works.)

Comment: I am receiving this error:
System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: '127.0.0.1.'